# MongoDB Atlas - How to fix 'TransientTransactionError' on shared web-hosting

Tags: node.js, shared-hosting, mongodb-atlas

`TransientTransactionError` when attempting to connect from shared web-host to Mongo Atlas

I actually had this working at one point but I had to wipe and restart my project from scratch on my web host. Now seemingly out of nowhere I keep getting the above-mentioned error when trying to connect to Atlas. I have already tried whitelisting IP addresses including both my server IP as well as 0.0.0.0/0 (the 'allow all' wildcard) in Atlas.

I have also tried using the 'full driver' snippet instead of mongoose but still receive the same error. Lastly, I want to point out that the exact same code works just fine on my local machine.

Here's my function:

```js
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const config = require("./config");
    module.exports = cb => {
        if (mongoose.connection.readyState < 1) {
            mongoose.connect(config.db).then(
                () => {
                    console.log("Database linking successful!");
                    return cb ? cb : null;
                },
                err => {
                console.log("Failed to connect to database.", err);
                }
            );
        }
    };
```

Here's what the error message looks like:

```js
{ MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [<mongodb-shard-goes-here>.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 54.145.177.180:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/titanesp/public_html/server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:431:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at connect (/home/titanesp/public_html/server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:557:14)
    at makeConnection (/home/titanesp/public_html/server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:39:11)
    at callback (/home/titanesp/public_html/server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:261:5)
    at TLSSocket.err (/home/titanesp/public_html/server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:286:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Comment: Something I neglected to mention is that the Mongo Uri (config.db in this case) is a string containing: "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<account name>-jhare.mongodb.net/<db name>?retryWrites=true" with the sensitive bits removed.

Comment: How did you solve this?